# Hiding horizontal scrollbar of IFrame in Facebook Application

Tags: facebook, iframe, width, scrollbar

I was looking for solutions, but most of it was outdated or doesn't work correctly.
At the of of my document (main file of FB application - index.php), I have added:

```
<script>
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
   $('#iframe_canvas').css({'overflow': 'hidden'});
   FB.Canvas.setAutoResize();
}
</script>
```

I was also trying with setSize({width and height}).
As I see previous versions has "remove scrollbars" option within Canvas settings - which is now removed. I was trying to change iframe, iframe > html and iframe > body CSS to overflow: hidden, overflow-x: hidden and many others. Also with JavaScript without effect.
Could anyone point the right path? Previously solutions found on stackoverflow doesn't help either.

Answer (score 0):

I would play with the two options in Advanced settings for your application called: Canvas width and Canvas height.  And see if a particular combination of those work.  Also the setAutoResize is being deprecated in favor of setAutoGrow(). See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Canvas.setAutoResize/